# What's next after Installing the RDS Role?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

I have set up Windows Server 2019 on my server called "RDS" and installed the Quick Session Based Role. The installed role services include RD Connection Broker, RD Session Host, RD Licensing, and RD Web Access. The RDS server is joined to a domain where a handful of other servers currently reside. This RDS server will also host the CALs required to support this effort.

When RDPing into one of the other servers on the domain, I'm still getting the message that says "there are too many users signed in". What do I need to set up next to allow multiple connections to the servers? Do I need to add these servers as session hosts on the RDS server in server manager?

The end goal is to allow multiple users to RDP into the servers from their laptops/workstations much like I do to do my admin tasks. Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, this server is internally facing. Not planning on setting up the RD Gateway unless that's the only option.

Comment: What do you mean by "RDPing into one of the other servers"? The CALs installed on RDS relate to RDP connections *to RDS* and cannot be used for other servers. You need to buy CALs for each server for which you want non-administrative logons.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I set up RDS on the domain, I'd be able to support having multiple connections on multiple servers across the domain. 

Is my understanding not correct? Does RDS need to be installed on every server you want multiple connections on?

Comment: RDPing into one of the other servers means that I tried logging in to one server with multiple RDP sessions and each with a different account and got hit with the "too many logged in message" when I tried logging in with a 3rd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CALs installed on a Windows server relate only to RDP connections
incoming to that server and cannot be used by any other server.
CALs cannot be shared with other servers - they only pertain to the
server on which they were installed.

You need to buy CALs for each server.

When you did RDP to servers for which you didn't install any CALs,
you were using the two administrative sessions that come with any Windows
server and hitting that limit.

Comment: Got it. In other words, a separate RDS server isn't really necessary. What needs to happen is you need to install the RDS role on your server(s) you want to open up connection wise and install the licenses there

Comment: Except that RDS is a heavy task. You really do not want an RDS server to share resources with other stuff unless you plan to only support up to 10 users max. If in the future you may grow to a larger size, setting up a separate server now is definitely preferred.

Comment: I have about 15 users i'll be supporting off the bat, am I better doing something like this? 

https://getanadmin.com/windowsserver/deploying-remote-desktop-services-on-windows-server-2019/

Comment: This link explains the mechanics of installing a single server, but does not explain the concept of CALs.